# How to rank a username based on its uniqueness?

Tags: python, math, statistics

Let's say I want to give a score for the uniqueness of a username (meaning the higher the score the less likely someone else has it). For example, the username "car" should have a very low score but "fastredcar1887$" should have a very high score.

My code works great and only have a low fail rate, But I think there are better ways. each letter of the alphabet increases the score by one. If there is numbers it increases the score by 2 and the total numbers of numbers in the name is to the power of 2, symbols are the same as numbers but not divided by 2.

```
scoreNum=(1/2*totalnumbers)^2+2
ScoreAlpha=totalalpha
ScoreSympol=(totalsymbols)^2+2
```

Then `totalscore=scoreNum+Scorealpha+scoresympol`

```py
def rating(name):
    rate=0
    num=0
    symbol=0
    thereisnum=False
    thereissymb=False
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if name[i].isnumeric():
            thereisnum=True

            num+=1
        if name[i].isalpha():
            rate+=1
        if name[i] in ",*&^%$#@:!()/\+-.~<>{}?=+@!#":
            thereisnum=True

            symbol+=1
    if thereisnum==True:


        rate+=int(round(1/2*(num)**2+2))
    if thereissymb==True:    
        rate+=int(round((symbol)**2+2))  
    return rate
```

I want to have better results for example, 123456789 is very common but my system rate it very high. I believe there are a lot of ways to better test the usernames. For example, some letters are rarer. What is the best way of dealing with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to check against very common usernames is simply to download a list of them (you could even copy-paste [a list like this](https://motivesense.com/common-bad-web-usernames/)) and reference it in your uniqueness code. That'd be much easier than trying to implement an algorithm that predicts what people commonly use as usernames.

Comment: It is very important for me to have a value for "uniqueness"

Comment: Inverse-rank the list then

Comment: I saw the list it is very small. Do you have huge ones? The problem is if the username not in the list that I have then it can't be compared to another usernames and will have infinite uniqueness.

Comment: I'm sure you could find a very large list online

Comment: And you could also use your algorithm in conjunction with the list. If not found in list, defer to your algorithm

Comment: I might combine the formula with the wordlist if  I can get a huge list of sorted common usernames. Is the formula good enough? I wrote it first try.edited: I was writing this when you posted lol.

Comment: Your algorithm is a good start, but you'd also want to implement detection of consecutive numbers/letters or common combos (like names or birthdays). Either way, the top 100 or so common usernames should definitely just be in a list.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Hopefully, I can find huge lists. Thank you

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped, would you mind accepting it? It'll grant you some rep :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure why you need this, 
In any case if want uniqueness you can't get it from some formula, You could use some dictionary module if word is there reduce your score.
A better way would be Google that word and reduce score depending on result count